# minimum sum of distances from vertices

Tags: geometry, optimization, triangles

Find a point on the plane of a triangle such that the sum of its distances from three vertices is minimum.

I am guessing that it is the centroid but I can't prove that.

Comment: Using calculus?

Comment: Preferably, not using calculus

Comment: Look here: [Fermat point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_point).

Comment: Works for me. Thanks